# Why is a cast from Double to <T : Number> possible, but not from Double to Int?

Tags: kotlin, generics, casting, classcastexception

In the following, I have a generic function `fun <T : Number> sum(list : List<T>) : T` with a type parameter `T : Number`.

In the function, I sum up the list's numbers as a `sum : Double` and cast the sum in the end with `return sum as T`.

For example, if a list of `Int` is passed, I also get back an `Int` - and this works.

```
fun <T : Number> sum(list : List<T>) : T {
    var sum = 0.0
    for(x in list)
        sum += x.toDouble()
    return sum as T
}
fun main() { println(sum(listOf(1,2,3))) } // prints 6
```

Yet, the following does not work, and I am wondering why the generic functions above works but directly casting a `Double` to an `Int` does not.

```
fun main() {        
    val d : Double = 6.0
    val i = d as Int // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    println(i)
}
```

I have to admit that I expected both cases to fail, but surprisingly, the generic function works and I don't know why.

So the question is: **Why does the generic function work and does not throw a ClassCastException when casting from Double to Int?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that in the first code snippet, which "works", you are not actually casting the result to `Int`. If you are using IntelliJ, it should have marked the cast as an "unchecked cast". This means that at runtime, it is not checked whether `sum` can actually be converted to type `T`. It only checks that `sum` is a `Number`, and that's it. Nothing else is performed.

You can see that the returned value is still a `Double`, not an `Int` by printing:

```
println(sum(listOf<Int>(1,2,3)) is Int) // false
println(sum(listOf<Int>(1,2,3)) is Double) // true
```

And as other answers explain, this is because of type erasure.

The reason why you still see `6`, but not `6.0` is bit more involved. The Kotlin compiler sees that the `sum` call here should return an `Int` (at this point the types have not been erased yet), so it finds the `println` overload that takes an `Int`, which inlines to the Java `System.out.prinln(int)` method. To call this method, the compiler must generate code that converts the type-erased `Number` that `sum` returns to an `int`, so it calls `Number.intValue`.

Therefore, this is what's generated:

```
  33: invokestatic  #69     // Method sum:(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/Number;
  36: invokevirtual #73     // Method java/lang/Number.intValue:()I
  39: invokevirtual #79     // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
```

If you had forced the compiler to call `pritnln(Any)`, then it would print `6.0`:

```
val any: Any = sum(listOf<Int>(1,2,3))
println(any)
```

Comment: And here we have the accepted answer, thank you for highlighting the "compiler magic" that makes it print as `6`!

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Perhaps I should add that, more generally, the compiler uses the `Number#xxxValue()`methods to unwrap wrapped numerical primitives, and the `XXX.valueOf()` methods to wrap primitive types into their wrappers when necessary. (Don't know if this is an implementation detail or behaviour that you can rely on though. The Kotlin/JVM spec hasn't been released the last time I checked)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure). In your case the generic info is only available during compile. At runtime the `sum as T` does noting, because it's not clear what T is. For example it's not possible to print out the type of T. It's an unchecked cast. You could also change the `T` type from `Number` to `String`, which makes no sense - but it would compile. So the function will not trow the `ClassCastException` because actual it does no cast. If you change the `sum` function to a [refined type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), which preserves the type info at runtime, it will do the cast and throw the error:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified  T : Number> sum(list: List<T>): T {
    var sum = 0.0
    for (x in list)
        sum += x.toDouble()
    return sum as T // java.lang.ClassCastException
}
```

Comment: I thought that it might be due to type erasure. But to me, it is still crazy that it prints the `6` correcly (because, if no cast is performed at all, it should still be the double `6.0` "somewhere internally").

Answer (score 1):

It does the cast, but the cast is to the upper bound of your generic type, which is `Number`

You can see this happening in the decompiled version of your code:

```java
   public static final Number sum(@NotNull List list) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(list, "list");
      double sum = 0.0D;

      Number x;
      for(Iterator var4 = list.iterator(); var4.hasNext(); sum += x.doubleValue()) {
         x = (Number)var4.next();
      }

      return (Number)sum;
   }
```

If you look at that code, the compiler will also tell you that casting to `T` is redundant, because this is already ensured.

The equivalent would be:

```kotlin
fun main() {        
    val d : Double = 6.0
    val i = d as Number 
    println(i)
}
```

Which doesn't cause ClassCast exception as well.

Comment: But if a `Number` is returned, how is it possible that `val s : Int = sum(listOf(1,2,3))` works, i.e., the static type of the `s` variable is `Int`. (Remark: `val s : Int = sum(listOf(1,2,3)) as Number` does (clearly) _not_ compile)

Comment: Also, how does printing the sum result in `6` instead of `6.0` if no cast to `Int` is performed?